# How to sync sources from Host to guest docker containers for a development reason

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I adjust a docker compose project for a development case. The main requirement is to synchronize sources from host to guest containers. **How exactly?** If it is so clear, give me an answer :) Beneath I will tell you my story for details. Thank you.

There are a lot of cases but no one works for me. I reuse this docker-compose.yml https://github.com/wodby/docker4drupal/blob/master/docker-compose.yml
I develop on Ubuntu. A) The docker documentation proposes the sshfs plugin based approach - https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#create-a-volume-using-a-volume-driver. But what host do I have to use? I see that guest containers connect to the host. B) Docker-sync approach seems weird https://github.com/EugenMayer/docker-sync/wiki/2.1-sync-commands . C) I've read the docker documentation once more and 've found a type of mounting **bind**. But do not see any good use cases. Internet uses the **C** variant docker-sync.

I also can not use docker compose long format for volumes https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#long-syntax.
The base project uses docker-compose format v2. I see that higher version of formats exist. Why do they still use this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of methods. The proper way is the docker volume driver for development needs.
To understand this better you need be introduced with:

- [Docker volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#short-syntax)
- [Configure bind propagation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-bind-propagation)

This a small patch from my docker-compose.yml

`- type: bind
    source: "${PROJECT_PATH}"
    target: /var/www/html
      bind:
        propagation: shared`

It works for me.